# Enable break times in javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm in the middle of an exercise on freecodecamp.com where we were asked to build a pomodoro timer similar to the one in [this link](http://codepen.io/GeoffStorbeck/full/RPbGxZ/)

I approached it by trying to format two date objects and find the difference then try to format it into min:sec format i.e 2:05 format (there might be lots of better ways).
I've been able to write up to a point where I can start the timer, pause the timer and also continue the timer from the paused point. However, if I set the end time to be `new Date("July 21, 1983 00:01:05")` I noticed that the timer jumps from 1:00 to 0:58.
Also the exercise says there should be a break time i.e the break time should start after the session time ends and when the break time ends the session time should start again. This I've not been able to replicate. I tried to create another set of date objects with the break time i wanted to compare and then countdown but when it ends, it starts the break time over again instead of jumping to the session time. I really do not want to copy codes from finished exercises, I want to figure this out myself (with some help if necessary).

```
    <div id="update"></div>
 <button class="start" onclick="count()">start</button>
    <button class="pause" onclick=" pause() ">Pause</button>
    <button class="play" onclick=" play() ">Continue</button>

<script>
    var start = new Date("July 21, 1983 0:00:00");
    var end = new Date("July 21, 1983 00:01:05");
    var difference = (end - start) / 1000;
    var min = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var sec = difference % 60;
    updateTarget(min, sec);
    var paused = false;

function count() {
        if (paused === false) {
            if (min > 0 || sec > 0) {
                if (sec === 0) {
                    min--;
                    sec = 60;
                    sec--;
                    updateTarget(min, sec);
                }
                sec--;
                updateTarget(min, sec);
                var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    count();
                }, 1000);
                if (min === 0 && sec === 0) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function pause() {
        paused = true;
    }
    function play() {
        paused = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            count();
        }, 1000);
    }
    function updateTarget(min,sec) {
        var target = document.getElementById("update");
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        target.innerHTML = min + ": " + sec;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try an approach using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` - this will help you avoid calling `count` too many times and overloading (try spamming the Continue button in your example)

Comment: @NickZ  setInterval messed up the whole thing. Time started jumping in random strides of about 12 seconds.

Comment: I meant to *change your approach* by using `setInterval` - simply replacing your `setTimeout` with a `setInterval` won't work on your current program. Since you're learning and don't want any spoilers, I don't want to write the code for you; instead just give you hints :)

Comment: **[here is a fiddle with a working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ba07a0to/10/)** feel free to reference this if you're stuck

Comment: @NickZ i get what you mean by spamming the continue button in my code. Did that and i noticed the timer starts jumping erratically. Your setInterval method fixes this. Is there a way I can incorporate the break time in the question?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're going from 60 to 58 is because you are decrementing twice after the flip (0->60). Remove the decrement inside the if and that should fix that:

```
            if (sec === 0) {
                min--;
                sec = 60;
                updateTarget(min, sec);
            }
```

Also, your termination test at the end is faulty, because when seconds === 0, you reset it to 60 before checking the minutes. The check for this should be inside the previous test. Try something like this:

```
            if (sec === 0) {
                if (min === 0) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    return;
                }
                min--;
                sec = 60;
                updateTarget(min, sec);
            }
```

and remove the termination test at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines could do...

```
 <div id="update"></div>
 <button class="start" onclick="start()">start</button>
    <button class="pause" onclick="pause() ">Pause</button>

<script>

    var toGo = 1000 * 60 * 2 // 2 minutes for the first working period
    var state = 'work';
    var timer

    function start(){
        timer = setInterval(function(){
            if(toGo <= 0){
                if(state == 'work'){
                    state = 'break';
                    toGo = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 means one minute for the break
                }
                else if(state == 'break'){
                    state = 'work';
                    toGo = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 means two minutes for the working period
                }
            }
            toGo = toGo - 1000
            var now = new Date(toGo)
            document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds()+' '+state;
         }, 1000);
    }

    function pause(){
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: your timer starts jumping erratically after the first "work" period

Comment: your timer starts with a 2 minutes work time and then goes to a 1 minute break time which is alright, but after that first pass, it just started doing 1 minute work and then 1 minute break which doesnt seem right.

Comment: Sure! I coded it that way. If you want to change the work duration or the brake duration change the toGo value in the if/else if block! toGo = 1000 * 60 * yourDesiredMinuteCount...